# Android Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some files in firebase database , I want to access those files in my app. In my app I have list of all those files and I want that on clicking on that particular file , it will be downloaded . Everything is working fine, but on clicking the item app crashes.

Giving the error:

> "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to
>   handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@2b2895d }"

Please help me out !

```
package com.example.shyamlal.uploadlist;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    List<Upload> uploadList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            uploadList = new ArrayList<>();
            listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
            //adding a clicklistener on listview
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    //getting the upload
                    Upload upload = uploadList.get(i);

                    //Opening the upload file in browser using the upload url
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(upload.getUrl()));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            //getting the database reference
            mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

            //retrieving upload data from firebase database
            mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        uploadList.add(upload);
                    }

                    String[] uploads = new String[uploadList.size()];

                    for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
                        uploads[i] = uploadList.get(i).getName();
                    }

                    //displaying it to list



                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uploads);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            });


        }
    }
```

Comment: At which line of code this error occurs?

Comment: startActivity(intent); At this line.

Answer (score 0):

I think it very clear, it's error at:

```
//Opening the upload file in browser using the upload url
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(upload.getUrl()));
 startActivity(intent);
```

edit, plz check null before call

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(upload.getUrl()); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Do you check null?

Comment: How will i do that ? Will you please elaborate ?

Comment: Try with default url: Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store");
If it's work maybe **upload.getUrl()** is null;